# HTML5 required parameter displayed outside of the page

Tags: html, textarea, required

I have a required attribute on a textarea that has an editor on it. The problem is that if the field is empty, the message "Please fill out this field." appears on the bottom left corner outside of the page.

The exact behavior can be seen here: http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=4768

[image]

Comment: atleast some code or screenshot would be nice

Comment: code. we need code. have you inspected this message on the bottom-left corner? the css or dom placement should tell you why it's all the way down there.

Comment: I attached a screenshot.

Comment: Text area not get the value of editor at client side you need to do validation at serverside

Comment: @ManishaPatel It is getting because if I put something there, the validation is ok.

Comment: Can you check with firebug or inspect element bocoz i have face the same problem

Comment: you just give that validation attribute on typing text place, remove from textarea.

Comment: I think you have to touch on Js to add that attribute. Can you do fiddle?

Comment: Here is a clear description of what happens there: http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=4768 I am not using tinyMCE but have the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround i used for that is not to use html5 required for this the Editod textarea field, but use a javascript validation instead.